# Couchbase Lite 2.1 Replicator Issue .net

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

We have just upgraded our SyncGatewaty to 2.1. So now I’m refactoring our client code to use CouchbaseLite 2.1. When I try to replicate I get the error:

> Got LiteCore error: Not Found (6/404)

I originally got the error when connecting to our Dev Server, and then installed a local `clean` copy on my laptop and I get the same error when trying to connect to it too.

Log:

> INFO) Couchbase 2019-01-10T10:56:47.8503147-07:00 (Startup) [1] CouchbaseLite/2.1.2 (.NET; Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763 ) Build/13 LiteCore/ (15) Commit/9aebf28
>
> WARNING) LiteCore 2019-01-10T10:56:48.1943139-07:00 {C4SocketImpl#1}==> class litecore::repl::C4SocketImpl ws://localhost.com:443//_blipsync
>
> WARNING) LiteCore 2019-01-10T10:56:48.1943139-07:00 {C4SocketImpl#1} Unexpected or unclean socket disconnect! (reason=WebSocket status, code=404)
>
> ERROR) Sync 2019-01-10T10:56:48.1993137-07:00 {Repl#2}==> class litecore::repl::Replicator c:\temp\content_meta_data.cblite2\ ->ws://localhost:443//_blipsync
>
> ERROR) Sync 2019-01-10T10:56:48.1993137-0
>   7:00 {Repl#2} Got LiteCore error: Not Found (6/404)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Couchbase.Lite;
using Couchbase.Lite.Support;
using Couchbase.Lite.Sync;
using NLog;

namespace ReplicatorExample
{
    public class DatabaseManager
    {
        private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public const string BUCKET_CONTENT_META_DATA = "content_meta_data";
        private static DatabaseManager _instance;

        public static DatabaseManager GetInstance()
        {
            NetDesktop.Activate();
            NetDesktop.EnableTextLogging("logs");

            return _instance ?? (_instance = new DatabaseManager());
        }

        public void InitializeBuckets()
        {
            try
            {
                var defaultAuthenticator = GetDefaultAuthenticator();

                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo($"c:\\temp\\{BUCKET_CONTENT_META_DATA}");
                if (!dirInfo.Parent.Exists)
                {
                    dirInfo.Parent.Create();
                }

                var database = new Database(dirInfo.FullName);

                // Create replicator to push and pull changes to and from the cloud
                var targetEndpoint = new URLEndpoint(new Uri("ws://localhost:4985"));
               var replConfig = new ReplicatorConfiguration(database, targetEndpoint)
                {
                    Authenticator = defaultAuthenticator,
                    Continuous = true,
                    //Channels = new List<string>
                    //{
                    //    "approved",
                    //    
                    //}
                };
                var replicator = new Replicator(replConfig);
                replicator.AddChangeListener((sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Status.Error != null)
                    {
                        _log.Error($"{args.Status.Error}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _log.Debug(args.Status);
                    }
                });
                replicator.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error(e);
            }
        }

        private Authenticator GetDefaultAuthenticator()
        {
            return new BasicAuthenticator("BigD","123456");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify the database name in the URL for `targetEndpoint`.

E.g: `var targetEndpoint = new URLEndpoint(new Uri("ws://localhost:4984/mydatabase"));`